# Can i restrict users from using my app when user has declined let say, like push notifications

Tags: java, android, ios, notifications

I am currently working on app, that in my thougths require push notifications, users can turn them off, but app needs them, so i am just showing alert to user "You need to allow push notifications to use this app", is it allowed in Android and IOS? Are there any restrictions, like "i have to let user use the app even when notifications turned off"

Comment: On Android, there is no need to ask to allow push notifications, but the user can disable them in the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` which you can use in android to automatically check every time when user is using your app. Something like below:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(yourCurrentActivity, Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Permission is not granted (You can perform whatever functionality you want to if permission is denied)
}
```

If the app has the permission, the method returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, and the app can proceed with the operation. If the app does not have the permission, the method returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`, and the app has to **explicitly** ask the user for permission.

You can read more in [**here.**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-check)

However, this is not the case with IOS applications. You **cannot restrict** the application to use a certain permission like push notification in your case. You can follow some [best practices.](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/) These are stringent guidelines from developers as well which you have to stick to. Read [**this**](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/) for the IOS push notification guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's app review guidelines:

> 4.5.4 Push Notifications must not be required for the app to function, and should not be used for advertising, promotions, or direct marketing purposes or to send sensitive personal or confidential information. Abuse of these services may result in revocation of your privileges.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design